# How to iterate the python dictionary to use the value to multiply it with some other value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

#dictionary

```
pname_price = {"phone":800,"laptop":1500,"refrigerator":1050,"speaker":200,"geyser":400}
```

#Question - Calculate the total price for the customer including the discount.

```
Total_price = unit_price*quantity*0.9 #0.9 is for 10% discount
```

(my question is how should I iterate the above dictionary if I want to multiply any of those values to multiply it with quantity to get the total_price.)

#Question - The total price will be displayed as a formatted message to the user, e.g.

```
<customer name> purchased <quantity> x <product name>
Unit price: <product price>
Total price: <total price>
```

(and how to print the above question, if I'm taking the name from user storing it in a list and the product name is in dictionary)

Comment: Please show what you have tried and where you get stuck

Comment: @MikaelÖhman, I used values() to get the value but can't complete it bcoz I want it for a specific value from the above dictionary and it returns a list of all the values from the dictionary

Answer (score 1):

for the first question, you can do the following ->

values = pname_price.values()

total = sum(values)
/* and to add the discount */ *0.9

Comment: Thank you, but values() will help me to get all the values but what if I want a specific value from my dictionary, ex - I want the value of refrigerator which is 1050 to multiply it with quantity

Comment: then I think you can add a condition if there is quantity then you will iterate, if not use values

Comment: <customer name> purchased <quantity> x <product name>
Unit price: <product price>
Total price: <total price>